# How to analyze what external files the sas program uses to generate a report

Tags: logging, sas

I have never used SAS and have a very poor understanding of it. I am given a SAS program that generates a report based on different excel files. Can I somehow get a file with information of what excel files did the program used and when (exact time) each file was used.

The code is vast and it would be better not to change anything inside it. I have seen that there is a SAS Log or SAS Logging facility and suppose that I should use it somehow. But as far as I understand that it can provide information about factors from Logging Thresholds(TRACE, DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, and FATAL), while I only need the name of the file and the time when it was used.

Sorry if the question is dumb, I have never used SAS. Thanks for help :)

Comment: When each file was used?  Do you mean accessed or created?  You can either edit the script to maintain the data and write it somewhere.  Or you can parse the log file to recreate the information.  Some coding is required.

Comment: That isn't available by default.  If the code has a macro in it then you won't be able to scan the code to determine usage as its based on the macro execution.

Comment: Thanks for advices :)